# ASP.NET 4 - MS SQL Server 2008 Hosting suggestion

Tags: shared-hosting

I am looking for a ASP.NET 4 and MS SQL Server 2008 hosting. I will program my web sites with ASP.NET 4 and MVC 2. But i could not decide a hosting. Can you suggest me a hosting company? It will be very helpfull if you are using or used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Discount ASP for my new .NET 4 project with SQL Server 2008.
http://discountasp.net
No problems so far.

$10/month for site hosting.
$10/month for SQL hosting.

They allow remote management and remote connections unlike a lot of other hosts.
Also, the web host is run under full trust. I got pretty pissed at hosting.com when they switched from full trust to medium...making most of my site useless, because I couldn't use webservices anymore.

They also have MVC hosting